# What are the different meanings of “God” in the New Testament?

Tags: trinity

The doctrine of the Trinity means that I am unable to follow references to “God” in the New Testament.

I would like a list of all references to “God” in the New Testament, showing whether each refers to

1. God the Father,
2. God the Son, or
3. God the Holy Spirit.

I honestly admit that the Trinity has confused me, and now I do not know who is talking to whom, who the Son is addressing, who the Father is addressing, and who the Holy Spirit is addressing. What God do the apostles address in books from Acts onwards?

The Bible ceased to have any logical meaning for me when people write about the triune God, but when I read “God” in the Bible, I don”t know when God is One, and when he is triune.

Comment: I think that this is an *interesting* question, but perhaps a little outside of what we can usefully handle here. Christianity SE is an unusual site, and has very strict rules about how to formulate a question and what counts as "on topic".

Comment: That is, I will never know what God is meant in each verse where we have a separate word for "God".
I have asked several hundred people throughout my life and no one has answered me, everyone avoids the answer, because none of the several hundred people I wrote down knows anything about it.

Comment: Well, you're not going to get an answer from me (I'm not a Christian; I just hang out here sometimes). To whip this question into a format that's allowed on this site, it needs to be addressed to a specific belief system. That doesn't necessarily mean a specific sect: something as broad as "Trinitarian Christians" (which is almost all Christians) will probably suffice for this one. But you're asking for a lot of work (every single verse that mentions God), so you might be waiting a while for an answer.

Comment: Is there at least one Bible translation or Application (Tool) that can indicate when a verse is referring to God the Spirit, to God the Son, and to God the Father?

Comment: @Steve This question is clearly directed to Trinitarians, so it's not an appropriate place to promote other theologies.

Comment: A very interesting question and important exercise for anyone who wants to test whether Trinitarianism makes sense scripturally. I have tried on this site to get straight answers for much more specific passages - good luck!

Comment: Such a list as is requested is well beyond the scope of this site. The list would run to thousands of entries.

Comment: Nigel J - What is the problem with creating a "pastebin text" with verses that, for example, will mean the third person "God-Holy Spirit" where there is a separate "God"?

Answer (score 4):

All you need to get a list of all the times and places in the Bible where the word "God" appears, is a Bible Concordance. I have a printed copy for the New International Version, and there are 16 full pages, with 230 entries per page = 3,680. The number of times there is God's (with an apostrophe = belonging to God, or pertaining to God) is 205, giving a total of 3,885.

I believe you can access such Concordances on-line, but because I'm using a printed book, it only took me five minutes to count the number of times. There are a couple more columns (77 entries per column) but there's a need to discount mention of any of the gods of the pagans.

Don't forget, either, that you would also need to look at the entries for 'Lord' when it is printed in capitals (the way that the Old Testament God of the Israelites is sometimes written.) That comes to 6,973 times in the Hebrew Scriptures (but not even once in the Christian Greek scriptures.) The number of times Lord is written in the Christian Greek scriptures is approximately 690 times, but it can apply either to the Father, or to the Son.

This means there are some **11,548 times in the whole of the Bible where God, God's, Lord and Lord's occurs**, **out of which there are about 1381 times in the New Testament**. You are not going to come to grips with the Trinity doctrine going about it by an individual check of each occurrence of such words.

***The best way would be to get a working definition of the Trinity, then to read whole sections with that in mind.*** The Christian Greek Scriptures show the appearing of the Son of God on the earth, as the virgin Mary's child, Jesus, so that would be the best place to start. Jesus mainly referred to his Father in heaven, clearly showing that distinction when he was on earth. And the Father spoke from heaven three times calling Jesus his Son. Those bits are clear, so start there, in the gospel accounts, is my encouragement.

Here's a working definition of the Trinity doctrine: ***The Father and the Son share the one divine nature, with absolute unity of the Spirit in that nature.*** You may like to ask other questions about that, to help come to grips with what is the deepest doctrine there can possibly be. Or, perhaps it would be easier for you to start with what the Bible, and Jesus, say about the Son of God, in the Christian Greek Scriptures, then come back to the Trinity doctrine after you've done that.